# How to get customer name and adress through order increment id/order id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, orders, event-observer

I want to fetch and show which customer bought which product and from where on front end. The issue is i am unable to fetch the above details through order increment id/order id.

[image: Here is my front end templates]

[image: Here is my observer]

So how can i get customer details on `checkout_onepage_success` page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well i would suggest to use `Automatic Dependency injection` but if you are using object manager then you can do it like this

```
<?php //NOT TESTED THOUGH
      --------------------
//Get Object Manager Instance
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($IncrementId); //Use increment id here.
$order->getCustomerName(); // Check that class. There are lot of functions for getting customers data. Though first you should check if any API available. Because thats a better solution.
```

Comment: Thanks @Kingshuk for giving solution, but  i'm not using any api.

Comment: No..not API..Magento said they can change the core code but not the APIs available in near future. If you go to `app\code\Magento\Sales` the first folder is API. Though you are good to go now. You can use the above code now i guess. But magento can change the core code anytime.

Comment: Thanks @Kingshuk for your help. It's working. You made my day man. :)

Comment: Great. Good to know @BikashRanjan

Comment: up vote plz @Kingshuk

Comment: does $order->getCustomerEmail(); give the customer email?

Comment: It might not provide exact customer name in case of Guest order. use @T P T solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// logined customer
 if ($order->getCustomerFirstname()) {
   $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
 } else {
  // guest customer
   $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
   $customerName = $billingAddress->getFirstname() . ' ' . 
   $billingAddress->getLastname();
 }
echo $customerName;
```

?>

Comment: Please provide a commentary with your answer, to explain your approach and how it works.

Comment: checking customer is guest or not. first name and Last name of the billing address is set as a customer name when the customer is guest.